# Why are COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME and -p ignored in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Why are my COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME and -p ignored in docker-compose?

I thought these were supposed to prepend the service names to help me organize my namespace but it seems that they are completely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question to hopefully save someone else the effort.

I had used the `container_name` option n my `docker-compose.yml`. Seems like if you do that then the nifty `-p` flag does not apply.

Comment: You seem unclear about `-p` we use `ports` and `expose` for ports in docker-compose  what is the usecase of -p here

Comment: Maybe we're talking about different versions? At https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/ I see documentation on docker-compose about -p referring to project name. See also https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me :( It ignores the -p and I don't have any container_name in my docker-compose.yml

@tara seems confused about the issue.

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung the -p flag is used in the docker-compose up command, not in the docker-compose.yml file.